# Qt way to get libraries path

Tags: qt, cmake

I have several `QPlugins` (shared objects) that I install `{CMAKE_PREFIX}/lib/<appname>`,  how can I find out this path at runtime to load the plugins? Note that the `CMAKE_PREFIX` user user settable.

Answer (score 0):

If these plugins are part of your application project and you are looking for a build time answer, you can generate a `config.h` file containing that path.

You can use CMake's [configure_file command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) for that.

Comment: The plugins may not be part of the project. Users can extend the app themselves.The path is set at configure stage (cmake) but used at runtime.

Comment: In that kind of setup, you usually have a known place for the plugins like used by Qt for its own sets of plugins e.g. `exe_path/plugins/mycoolplugins/`. If you want your application users to be able to put plugins somewhere else and still be able to load them, then you should add a setting somewhere to add search paths that your application will use to discover and load additional plugins.